# Математическая постановка заполнения матрицы

Tags: c#

Есть простая задача. Сформировать матрицу X, порядка n. Элементы матрицы нужно рассчитывать по следующей.

формуле

```
xij = min(i, j, n - i + 1, n - j + 1)
i, j = 1...n
```

Правильно ли я сделал заполнение?

Задаю вопрос, поскольку не уверен, правильно ли я выполнил заполнение.

Сделал таким образом

```
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                // заполняем по формуле
                min = j;

                if (j < min && i < min)
                    min = j;

                if (n - i + 1 < min)
                    min = n - i + 1;

                if (n - j + 1 < min)
                    min = n - j + 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Неправильно, например, в первом `if` условие всегда будет ложным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    x[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(i, j), Math.Min(n - i + 1, n - j + 1));
```